# React elements that are selectable and draggable

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm using [react-selectable-fast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-selectable-fast) on a list of items that can be selected. However an item or a group of selected items should also be draggable, which is implemented using [react-dnd](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd).

The issue is that the selecting comes in the way of dragging; when hovering on top of an item and trying to drag it I end up selecting instead.

I've managed to fix the issue with a hack: store in state whether currently hovering an item or a group of selected items and if so `disable` the `<SelectableGroup>`. However this means that the whole list of items is rerendered every time I move the mouse over an item.

So I would like a better solution but I haven't been able to find one. In the last attempt I put the draggable element (using `connectDragSource`) on top of the selectable element (using `createSelectable`) again on top of `<SelectableGroup />` and gave them increasing `z-index`es, also tried playing around with `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()` but still the selecting overrides the dragging.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you finally resolve this issue? If you got the z-index workaround to work, what was the trick?

Comment: I ended up using the prop called `ignoreList` from react-selectable-fast. I give the elements a class `disable-select` and then set `ignoreList={['.disable-select:hover']}`